# Creating a formula using INDEX and IF

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to create a formula where I take the newest value on a cell. The information is updated when someone fills out the Google Form. Basically, there is some information the customer might not fill out, so the information is sparse.

What I want to create is a formula where it always takes the very bottom value of the spreadsheet (newest information). Even if the cell was blank, I want it to output as blank, and if there is an information on that cell, output it as that written value. Is this possible using INDEX and IF formula? Or is there some other formula to solve this problem.

If this doesn't make sense, please comment and I'll answer.

```
=INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A))
```

Comment: Do you have any `required field` in form. `Required Field` means user must enter data on that field. If so then you can use `CountA()` formula for that field.

Comment: There are some cases where the customer is not required to fill out the form. This is why depending on the customer, there are a lot of blank spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let form sheet be:

[image: 0]

then to get last form entry row use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("form!"&
 MAX(IF(form!A:A<>"", ROW(form!A:A), ))&":"&
 MAX(IF(form!A:A<>"", ROW(form!A:A), ))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you very much for your help.